# Extracting the cover image from a word document

Tags: ms-word, rendering, document, java

My task involves extracting the cover image in a word document.The heuristics that I am following is "if the first page of the document contains only an image then it is a cover image otherwise there is no cover image ".So i need to get the content of the first page alone and check if it has only an image.How can i do it ?

I tried a bunch of wordprocessing API like POI,docx4j,etc . But these API doesnt have any provisions to identify a particular page's content.I have also tried to write my own XML parsing.I understand that word document is reflowable and openxml of the docxfile doesnt have any clue regarding implicit page breaks.
I have posted a [question regarding this]: [Finding implicit page break in word document using xml parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720972/finding-implicit-page-break-in-word-document-using-xml-parsing/24721569#24721569)
and there were no helpful answer. 
So if this cannot be done via xml parsing of the openxml of the word document, what is the best way to do it ? Is there any helpful API in Java for this task ?